# Why Bootstrap css overlaps angular material custom css

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

Here is my custom `css` on Angular Material's `mat-table` that is placed at `styles.css`.

```
.mat-column-action1 {
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

My `col` definition looks

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action1">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let e; let i = index;">
        <span *ngIf="i == mouseOverIndex" (click)="edit(e.id)"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

This works as expected. Now, I added `@import "../lib/bs4.min.css";` at first line of `styles.css`. Since then above custom `css` of `.mat-column-action1` not working properly.

What I tried?

Moved `@import` statement at the end line in `styles.css` like below. But entire `bs4.css` styles not working.

```
.mat-column-action1 {
  min-width: 20px;
}

@import "../lib/bs4.min.css";
```

Added `::ng-deep` but no effect.

```
::ng-deep .mat-column-action1 {
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

Added `!important;` to the width

```
.mat-column-action1 {
  min-width: 20px !important;
}
```

What else am I missing here to work with both `bs4.min.css` and `Angular Material`'s mat-table.

Note: I use both `mat-table` and `bs4` table in my components.

Update for @Joel

In `styles.css`

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import "../lib/bs4.min.css";
@import "../lib/mdb.min.css";

 table {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .mat-header-cell {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

.mat-column-action1 {
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

In `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Comment: Try :host >>> .mat-column-action1 {
  min-width: 20px;
}

Comment: @Ramesh i would like to now how you  have imported all your custom  css files to you angular app starting from boottsrap.min.css, style.css, materia.css  and  their order  and their location of import

Comment: @atul, No Luck.

Comment: @JoelJoseph, I updated my question with `styles.css and angular.json` code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using both Bootstrap and Material you're going to have problems - Bootstrap adds styles directly onto HTML elements, so it will mess with Material components using those HTML elements, i.e. table.

Basically you have two options if you really NEED to use both:

1. Use mat-table without HTML `<table>` element. You can read more about it [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#accessibility) (see Tables with display: flex section - I linked directly to it but it seems the page "jumps" after some data is loaded).
2. Prepare your own Bootstrap package excluding some stylesheets, i.e. `_tables.scss` file so that it doesn't overwrite your styles.